# Drop table in mysql with Create statement

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table, drop-table

I'm facing this issue where I'm trying to drop the table if it exists but I keeping getting error. Here's what I have

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clips_cur;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE clips_cur(
SELECT year_r, month_n_r, IFNULL(SUM(current_clip_count),0) as curclips
FROM data_mining.clip_summary stb 
JOIN mstr_all_offer_sum o 
JOIN mstr_all_clip_red_sum d
WHERE stb.offer_id=o.oid AND
d.offer_id = o.oid AND
clip_date>='2022-03-01'AND 
clip_date>=SUBDATE( o.st_d, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
clip_date<=ADDDATE(o.end_d, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
clip_date<='2022-03-28' AND
is_handraiser<>1 
group by year_r, month_n_r)
```

Here's the error:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE clips_cur( SELECT year_r,
> month_n_r, IFNULL(SUM(current_' at line 2
>
> Error position: line: 1

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi to create table from Query use "AS" not "()" try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clips_cur;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE clips_cur
AS
SELECT year_r, month_n_r, IFNULL(SUM(current_clip_count),0) as curclips
FROM data_mining.clip_summary stb 
JOIN mstr_all_offer_sum o 
JOIN mstr_all_clip_red_sum d
WHERE stb.offer_id=o.oid AND
d.offer_id = o.oid AND
clip_date>='2022-03-01'AND 
clip_date>=SUBDATE( o.st_d, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
clip_date<=ADDDATE(o.end_d, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
clip_date<='2022-03-28' AND
is_handraiser<>1 
group by year_r, month_n_r
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this and still have error thrown at me

Comment: same error? or different error, because "and still have error thrown at me" is a bit general... 

Comment: This the error 
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE clips_cur as
SELECT year_r, month_n_r, IFNULL(SUM(curren' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

I tried and Work to me, you have error with JOIN its incomplete
you need relation fields using "ON" not "WHERE"

example:

```
Select t1.field1,t2.field1 
From Table1 t1
Join Table2 t2 on t1.fkfield = t2.keyfield
Where t1.id = 1
```

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Test your SELECT statement  first, before CREATE  statement, to ensure

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clips_cur;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE clips_cur 
AS
SELECT year_r, month_n_r, IFNULL(SUM(current_clip_count),0) as curclips
FROM data_mining.clip_summary stb 
JOIN mstr_all_offer_sum o
ON stb.offer_id=o.oid 
JOIN mstr_all_clip_red_sum d
ON d.offer_id = o.oid
WHERE clip_date>='2022-03-01'AND 
clip_date>=SUBDATE( o.st_d, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
clip_date<=ADDDATE(o.end_d, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
clip_date<='2022-03-28' AND
is_handraiser<>1 
group by year_r, month_n_r 
This is what I have it as right now, and still throws in error

Comment: Select statement worked in both the cases, even the create statement worked in both cases